# could not to setup crash dump on centos7 for debug kernel

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, crash, centos7

I am trying to setup kdump to generate the vmcore for kernel-3.10.0-123.el7. For the perf kernel kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.rpm i setup kdump and kdump is working fine too, generating vmcore.
Then i installed

> kernel-debug-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.rpm

using yum install kernel-debug-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.rpm and kdump worked fine.

But then i didnt have vmlinux to read vmcore of debug kernel.
Then I build source using rpmbuild from the source

> kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.src.rpm

But I see the vmlinux in

> ~/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-3.10.0-123.el7/linux-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64/vmlinux
>
> for perf kernel only not for debug kernel

So from ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES

> i copied linux-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.tar.xz and used
>   kernel-3.10.0-x86_64-debug.config as .config to get vmlinux

When i used this newly built vmlinux for debug kernel with crash it threw error that kernel version mismatch. Now I am stuck.

Please help me in setting up the kdump on centos7 with debug kernel & debug vmlinux.

Comment: You should use your native system kernel vmlinux, what is the problem with this?

Comment: kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.rpm default kernel comes with centos7... one more thing i have installed centos7 on virtual box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am new to centos I was not aware of debug pakages has vmlinux. i have installed debug rpms using following command:

```
yum --enablerepo=debug install kexec-tools crash kernel-debug kernel-debuginfo-`uname -r`
```

I notice kernel-debuginfo-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 has vmlinux at location:

```
/usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64/vmlinux
```

So i got the vmlinux.

This vmlinux works with non-debug kernel.